# How to modify the top progress bar line when a page is loading just like Youtube and Github

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I want to modify the top progress bar line when a page is loading just like youtube and github which have red and blue line at the top respectively when they are loading. Is it possible to do it with pure **js**?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have no idea from where start or end or even try!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to make sure that your data is loaded asynchronously after your main page is loaded. Your main page has to include that progress bar to which you feed the progress of your async load-data requests. In order to display a realistig loading behaviour you need to chain multiple load calls in order to react to these responses and fill your progress bar respetivly.

For frontend it is possible to achieve that with pure js... But your backend needs to serve your website, data, etc. one after another.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm new to javascript, if possible can you explain deeply? If not then please send me a code snippet, i'll experiment with that. (I have no backend btw, it's just a practice website I was making)

Comment: Okay is see... You need some sort of backend to serve different parts for your page in order to feed a real progress bar... So for that its not possible with pure js... im sry